# Function to multiply array elements

Tags: c#, arrays, multiplication

im doing a calculator, this is the code:

If i go to the Multiplication function and i enter for example i want to multiple 2*2*2
this code it's outputting 4 8 4 
I dont understand why, well i know that 2*2 = 4 * 2 = 8 but why the last 4?
and how can i only get the result without getting the complete series?, when i try to do the Console WriteLine outside the for loops it throws an error. it doesn't let me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void LetsSum(int [] myArray)
        {
            int sum = myArray.Sum();
            Console.WriteLine(sum);     
        }

        static void  letsMult(int [] myArray)
        {  
            for (int a = 0; a < myArray.Length; a++ )
            {
                for (int b = a+1; b < myArray.Length; b++ )
                {
                int multip =  myArray[a] *= myArray[b];
                Console.WriteLine(multip);

                }

            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //First Variable total of numbers from users input
            int TotalNumb = 0;           
            //String to receive users input
            string TotalN = string.Empty;
            //Specifying size of array
            Console.WriteLine("Please specify how many numbers do you want to do the math");
            TotalN = Console.ReadLine();
            //Converte because readline it's a string
            TotalNumb = Convert.ToInt32(TotalN);
            //Name of ARRAY and passing the value selected by the user
            int[] myArray = new int[TotalNumb];

            //counter for the loop
            int i = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < TotalNumb; i++ )
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter your number");

                        myArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter SUM, LESS, MULT, DIV");
            string ToDo = Console.ReadLine();


                    if (ToDo == "SUM")
                    {
                        Program.LetsSum(myArray);
                    }

                    if (ToDo == "MULT")
                    {
                        Program.letsMult(myArray);
                    }

                    Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple... alter your code like as bellow...

```
 static void  letsMult(int [] myArray)
        {  
            int output=1;

            for (int a = 0; a < myArray.Length; a++ )
            {
                  output=output*myArray[a];
                  Console.WriteLine(output);
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because you're declaring `int multip` in the innermost scope of the for loop.  The int goes out of scope after that, and is not usable.  If you want `multip` to be accessible outside of the `for` loop, declare it outside of the for loop:

```
    static void  letsMult(int [] myArray)
    {  
        int multip = 1;
        for (int a = 0; a < myArray.Length; a++ )
        {
            for (int b = a+1; b < myArray.Length; b++ )
            {
              multip =  myArray[a] *= myArray[b];
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(multip);
    }
```

Note, it's *declared* above the for loop, but *used* in the loop, and outputted outside the loop, but still in its scope (which in my case is "the entire function").

You still have a logical issue.  Are you sure you need a nested loop?  How would you describe to a person how to multiply a list of numbers to get the total product?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 Elements in your Array

> [2, 2, 2]

Then you multiply 0 and 1 and output the result:

> [4, 2, 2] OUTPUT: 4

Then you multiply 0 and 2 and output the result:

> [8, 2, 2] OUTPUT: 8

The n you multiply 1 and 2 and output the result:

> [8, 4, 2] OUTPUT: 8

Perhaps you want to remove the outer loop, in this case your Output would be

> 4, 8

Answer (score 0):

use

```
int multip=1;

for (int a = 0; a < myArray.Length; a++ )
            {

                 multip  *= myArray[a];
                Console.WriteLine(multip);

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with LINQ's [Aggregate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

for sum :

```
  int[] arr1 = new int[] { 2, 2, 2 };
  int result = arr1.Aggregate((a, b) => b + a);
 //or
  int result = arr1.Sum();
```

for multiplication :

```
  int[] arr1 = new int[] { 2, 2, 2 };
  int result = arr1.Aggregate((a, b) => b * a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to display each multiplacation result.If so you can do the following:

```
int multip = myArray[0];
for (int a = 1; a < myArray.Length; a++ )
{
    Console.Write("{0} * {1} = ",multip, myArray[a]);
    multip *= myArray[a];
    Console.WriteLine(multip);
}
```